# Cannot find property set in componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know I'm missing something basic here and if someone could help I would really appreciate it. This code gives me a warning: "Cannot read property 'setState' of null."

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foundUser: false
}
   }

componentWillMount() {
  var requestEmail = this.props.email
  new Firebase(url)
    .orderByChild('email')
    .startAt(requestEmail)
    .endAt(requestEmail)
    .once('value', function (snap) {
      var foundUser = snap.val();
      if (foundUser) {
        this.setState({found: true})
      } else {
        this.setState({foundUser: false})
      } 
    });
},

render: function () {

  if (this.state.foundUser === false) {
    //render a scene here ...
  }

  return ( ....
```

Comment: May be you just forgot to create an initial state object in constructor, like `this.state = {foundUser: false}`

Comment: Yes, I did try that -- should have shown it. Then I get "Cannot read property 'setState' of null. I feel I'm not dealing correctly with scope.

Comment: Are you using redux? If yes, you can only access your state through this.props. If not, which line of your code show you the error?

Comment: No, I'm not using redux. It's showing the error on the first "this.setState" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the correct context of the component when you use `this`:

```
componentWillMount() {
  var self = this;
  var requestEmail = this.props.email
  new Firebase(url)
    .orderByChild('email')
    .startAt(requestEmail)
    .endAt(requestEmail)
    .once('value', function (snap) {
      var foundUser = snap.val();
      if (foundUser) {
        self.setState({found: true})
      } else {
        self.setState({foundUser: false})
      } 
    });
},
```

Save a reference to `this` in a variable, or you could use `.bind`, or even better es6 arrow function, since it looks like you are using es6.

```
  new Firebase(url)
    .orderByChild('email')
    .startAt(requestEmail)
    .endAt(requestEmail)
    .once('value', (snap) => {
      var foundUser = snap.val();
      if (foundUser) {
        this.setState({found: true})
      } else {
        this.setState({foundUser: false})
      } 
    });
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the initial state of the component, try to add following function to your component

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
     foundUser: false
  };
}
```